# Python: How can this code be made better?

Tags: python

WAP to create math application using function concept add minimum 20-25 functionalities different function for each functionalities and user input for selection of any function based on the functionality ask user for the input.

```
import math

def add(x, y):

   return x + y

def subtract(x, y):

   return x - y

def multiply(x, y):

   return x * y

def divide(x, y):

   return x / y

def floor(x , y):

  return x // y

def exponent(x, y):

  return x ** y

def remainder(x, y):

  return x % y

def square(x, y):

  a = x ** 0.5

  b = y ** 0.5

  return a,b

def swap(x, y):

  temp = x

  x = y

  y = temp  

  return int(x), int(y) 

def factors(x):

   print("The factors of",x,"are:")

   for i in range(1, x + 1):

       if x % i == 0:

           print(i)

def lcm(x, y):

   if x > y:

       greater = x

   else:

       greater = y


   while(True):

       if((greater % x == 0) and (greater % y == 0)):

           lcm = greater

           break

       greater += 1

   return lcm

def hcf(x, y):

    if x > y:

        smaller = y

    else:

        smaller = x

    for i in range(1, smaller+1):

        if((x % i == 0) and (y % i == 0)):

            hcf = i 

    return hcf   

def odd_even(x):

  if (x % 2) == 0:

   print("{0} is Even".format(x))

  else:

    print("{0} is Odd".format(x))

def factorial(x):

 return math.factorial(x)   

def absolute(x):

  return math.fabs(x)   

def power(x, y):

  return math.pow(x, y) 

def sin(x):

  return math.sin(x)    

def cos(x):

  return math.cos(x)

def tan(x):

  return math.tan(x)

def radian(x):

  return math.radians(x)    

print("Select operation.")

print("1.Add")

print("2.Subtract")

print("3.Multiply")

print("4.Divide")

print("5.Floor")

print("6.Exponent")

print("7.Remainder")

print("8.Square")

print("9.Swap")

print("10.Factors")

print("11.LCM")

print("12.HCF")

print("13.Odd or Even")

print("14.Factorial")

print("15.Absolute")

print("16.Power")

print("17.Sin")

print("18.Cos")

print("19.Tan")

print("20.Radian")

choice = input("Enter choice(1-20): ")

num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))

num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))


if choice == '1':

  print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1,num2))

elif choice == '2':

print(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))

elif choice == '3':

print(num1,"*",num2,"=", multiply(num1,num2))

elif choice == '4':

print(num1,"/",num2,"=", divide(num1,num2))

elif choice == '5':

print("Floor:", floor(num1,num2))

elif choice == '6':

print(num1,"** ",num2,"=", exponent(num1,num2))

elif choice == '7':

print(num1," % ",num2,"=", remainder(num1,num2))

elif choice == '8':

print("Square:", square(num1,num2))

elif choice == '9':

print("Swap:", swap(num1,num2))    

elif choice == '10':

print(factors(num1)) 

elif choice == '11':

print("LCM is:", lcm(num1,num2)) 

elif choice == '12':

print("HCF is:", hcf(num1,num2))   

elif choice == '13':

   print(odd_even(num1))

elif choice == '14':

  print("Factorial is:", factorial(num1))

elif choice == '15':

  print("Absolute value is:", absoulute(num1))

elif choice == '16':

  print("Power:", power(num1, num2))

elif choice == '17':

  print("Sin:", sin(num1))

elif choice == '18':

  print("Cos:", cos(num1))

elif choice == '19':

  print("Tan:", tan(num1))

elif choice == '20':

  print("Radian:", radian(num1))

else:

   print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get useful help, take a look at [the asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, please try to make your question as specific as possible. Also, if there are specific critiques you would like, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) might be a better place to ask. (As a first suggestion for how to improve it, you could format it to be easier to read. Indent in multiples of 4 spaces and don't add blank lines except in between functions and to make the code easier to read.)

Comment: At a cursory overview, I can say that you could use the built-in `pow` function instead of defining your own `exponent` function, and most of your other functions can be imported from the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) or [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) modules. Also, `swap` in Python can be written as `x, y = y, x` or `def swap(x, y): return y, x` (but it isn't useful as a function).

Comment: you could remove some empty lines to make it shorter. Don't create function `sin()` but use directly `math.sin()` - it will reduce code. Silimar with other `math` functions.

Comment: Make a dictionary `{user_response:function_name, ...}` then select the function with the user's response.. Make the user prompt for the desired operation one long string.